# Label.SizeToFit() Deprecated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is the `Label.SizeToFit()` function deprecated? Although I can find references to its past use, when I go to code it against current Xamarin Label object it is not available as a method.

Comment: iOS UILabel has a SizeToFit() method, but I don't believe the Forms Label has ever had one

Comment: @Jason Is correct, Xamarin.Forms has never had a `SizeToFit` API; it only exists in Xamarin.iOS. Here's the Xamarin.Forms source code showing that no `SizeToFit` API exists: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/search?q=SizeToFit&type=Code

Comment: Can you please mark the right answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SizeToFit` is a `UILabel` API. This means it is available in Xamarin.iOS, not in Xamarin.Forms.

[From Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit):

> Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.

In Xamarin.Forms, to ensure the `Label` fills only the space it needs in order to display the text (and does not expand to the screen bounds), use any of the following `LayoutOptions`:

- `Fill`
- `Center`
- `Start`
- `End`

**Note:** Avoid any `LayoutOption` ending in `...Expand`, e.g. `FillAndExpand`, `StartAndExpand`, etc., because this will tell Xamarin.Forms to expand the visible element to the bounds of its layout.

#### XAML

Here is an example centering the Label:

```xml
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

#### C#

Here is an example centering the Label:

```cs
var label = new Label
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
}
```